# Does .Net 4 inline MarshalByRefObject methods?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, inline, marshalbyrefobject

I have some code that relied on methods not being inlined :

```
internal class MyClass : BaseClass
{
    // should not be inlined
    public void DoSomething(int id)
    {
       base.Execute(id);
    }
}

public abstract class BaseClass : MarshallByRefObject
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    protected void Execute(params object[] args)
    {
         // does a stack walk to find signature of calling method
    }
}
```

Of course this does only work if the DoSomething method is not inlined. This is the reason why the base class derives from `MarshallByRefObject`, which prevent inlining of public methods.

It worked until now, but I got a stacktrace from a .Net 4 server showing that the stackwalk reached the caller of DoSomething.

Is the .Net 4 inlining more clever and detect that MyClass is internal and has no chance of being substituted with a proxy ?

Comment: Can't work here.  Only a call from outside of the class might have to be proxied.  When the jitter is asked to generate code for the class itself then it *knows* that a local instance of the type needs it.  So inlining is permitted.  The changed inlining rules for .NET 4 is what actually bytes you.

Comment: Actually, the DoSomething method is called from another class. That's why I think it should not be inlined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commenter here suggests that you also need to specify `NoOptimisation` to achieve what you want.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/162364/methodimpl-methodimploptions-noinlining-doesnt-work-correctly-on-x64

Comment: The function missing on the stack is DoSomething. The Execute method is not inlined. But I should add the nooptimisation anyway on Execute to be sure it would never inline it.